# DateTime won't change temporary

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

My whole site is:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
```

A user can select their timezone, and in the database it saves as `4.0` (for Dubai)

Now I wish to have so the timezone the user has chosen has an impact on the countdown, that exists on the site. The countdown looks like this:

```
    $today_date = new DateTime('now');  // now
    $final_date = new DateTime($date); // a date in the future
    $interval = $today_date->diff($final_date); // find the difference

    $time_left = $interval->format('starting in %d days, %h hours and %i minutes'); // display it
```

Above this, i did following:

```
        $userGMT = $user->get_gmt();
        date_default_timezone_set($userGMT);
```

Which does not work correct. It still counts down for Europe/London timezone, and not the one I have chosen.

I tried do echo date('H:i:s'); and can see by the time that the above has affected and it is showing the time for the timezone I have picked.

So that works, but dateTime('now'); doesnt?

Comment: Did you try `new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'))`?

Comment: Yes, did not work out for me either

Comment: Have you turned on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1')` to catch all possible errors (only in dev of course)? Are all timezones correctly installed? Check with `locale -a` in your console.

Comment: I dont have access to server config, but it should display all the errors if there was any..

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is add the `$userGMT` to your currentTime and then subtract your server time.  So get the time in seconds then add `$userGMT*60*60 - $yourTimeZone*60*60`

Answer (score 0):

When the date in the future is generated, it needs to be explicit about the applicable timezone.  This demonstrates that the interval is independent of the host's timezone:

```
<?php
$date = '2012-04-19';   // date in the future
$user_tz = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dubai');
foreach (array('Europe/London', 'America/Los_Angeles') as $tzname)
{
  date_default_timezone_set($tzname);
  $today_date = new DateTime('now');  // now
  $final_date = new DateTime($date, $user_tz); // future date with explicit tz
  $interval = $today_date->diff($final_date); // find the difference
  $time_left = $interval->format('start in %d days, %h hours and %i minutes');
  echo "$tzname:  $time_left\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Europe/London:  start in 0 days, 11 hours and 53 minutes
America/Los_Angeles:  start in 0 days, 11 hours and 53 minutes
```

Comment: So you're saying that what I wish to do is impossible, because uses the the host's timezone, no matter what?

Comment: @Karem:  Not at all.  The fix I propose is not affected by the host's timezone.

Comment: but in your output, it outputs the same hours/minutes left, in both europe/london and in america/los_angeles which is not right? America/Los_angeles which is GMT-8 should show in your example 3 hours left and 53 minutes

Comment: @Karem: Maybe I am not understanding you, but your statement `the timezone the user has chosen has an impact on the countdown`.  I thought it meant the host's timezone is not to be a factor in the time interval.  That says to me that each user configures their own timezone and countdowns are relative to their timezone.  That it what I encapsulated in `$user_tz`.